# apache camel split csv file

Tags: apache, apache-camel

We are having a requirement to split a large CSV into smaller multiple CSV files. 
First row of main CSV file contains the column header which I need to have in all generated CSV files.

How to achieve it?

I am able to split file using Apache Camel Splitter route as follows...

```
        <split id="LineItemSplitter" streaming="true"
            parallelProcessing="true" timeout="0">
            <tokenize token="\n" group="5000" />
            <to id="LineItemOutbox"
                uri="file:/target?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSSS}.csv?fileExist=Append" />
        </split>

    </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to handle that is to use the aggregator pattern and have the column headers added in the strategy class.

For example see below:

```
        <aggregate strategyRef="messageAggregatorStrategy">
            <correlationExpression>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </correlationExpression>
            <completionTimeout>
                <simple>10000</simple>
            </completionTimeout>
            <completionSize>
                <simple>500</simple>
            </completionSize>
            <to id="LineItemOutbox"
                  uri="file:/target?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSSS}.csv?fileExist=Append" />
        </aggregate>
```

Then your strategy bean:

```
<bean id="messageAggregatorStrategy" class="com.youorg.MessageAggregator" />
```

Then in your strategy you can set the column header:

```
public class MessageAggregator implements AggregationStrategy
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MessageAggregator.class);
    private String COLUMN_HEADERS = "a,b,c";

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange)
    {
        Exchange exchangeToReturn;
        StringBuffer csvBuffer;
        String csv = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        if (oldExchange == null)
        {
            csvBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            csvBuffer.append(COLUMN_HEADERS).append("\r\n");
            csvBuffer.append(csv);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(csvBuffer);
            exchangeToReturn = newExchange;
        }
        else
        {
            csvBuffer = (StringBuffer) oldExchange.getIn().getBody(StringBuffer.class);

            // update the existing message with the added body
            csvBuffer.append("\r\n");
            csvBuffer.append(csv);
            oldExchange.getIn().setBody(csvBuffer);

            // and return it
            exchangeToReturn = oldExchange;
        }
        return exchangeToReturn;
    }
```

The drawback of this approach might performance because you re-aggregate instead of direcly writing to the target file but it does achieve what you are looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But how to extract columns header from file which can be directly used in strategy???

Comment: You don't know ahead the columns headers? Are there multiple types of headers?

Comment: This is a single route which will be used for parsing different files. So Column headers will be there in each file. So first need to extract first line data which will be column headers and can be used above strategy.

Comment: If so you can just before the aggregate add a processor that will get each line and will know based on a header the name of the file as well as the line index, if line index == 0 you can jut put the columns headers in one of the exchange header.